# Playing .wav files with WebAudio, served by nginx

Tags: nginx, content-type, web-audio-api

I'm working on a project using the WebAudio API to play a number of .wav files. This works fine locally, but when I put the whole thing on my server, it does not work: `context.decodeAudioData` fails, and returns an empty error.

I noticed that all of the wav files were being served by nginx with a `Content-Type` of `text/html`. I've mapped `wav` to `audio/x-wav` in the nginx mime.types file, and when I run `curl -I` against these files, they come back correctly as `Content-Type: audio/x-wav`. But they persist in showing up in the browser as text/html, and this does not appear to be a browser caching issue.

Is the wrong Content-Type what's preventing these from playing? How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the MIME type shouldn't matter, since you're (hopefully) making the XHR with a `responseType` of `arraybuffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be: there was a problem with the URLs, and my nginx setup was not serving error pages properly.

Comment: Can you detail your answer please ? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter: decodeAudioData performs binary sniffing on the data to determine the type.

Do you have some code to show? It might be an issue with the XHR